# jQuery change background color on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, flexslider

I try to make animated background color on active slide using flexslider, but i don't find any idea how to do it... so i tryed to make something simple but not working good.

I Have 4 slide so i want to change only 4 color when a click a next slide...

jQuery

```
  $( function() {
  $('.dot li').click( function() {
    $('.wrapper').css('background', '#749e4f');
    $('.dot li').click( function() {
    $('.wrapper').css('background', '#d16b42');

  });
});
```

Navigation | Flexslider

```
<div class="slider-nav">
<ul class="dot">
<li><a href="#">iphone 5<span class="bullet">1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#">htc one <span class="bullet">2</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#">ipad mini<span class="bullet">3</span></a> </li>
<li><a href="#">droid z<span class="bullet">4</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for any idea :)

Comment: can u produce the fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R9uf9/1/ Thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you, Since you are a beginner, I would like to explain the following code a bit for your better understanding.

1. Hold the colors in an `array`. The array's length must be the count of the li that you are having.
2. Create a common `click` handler for all the `li` elements.(It was already in your code)
3. And inside the click handler, Just change the color of your target element by referring from the array in accordance with the `index` of the clicked Li element.

   ```
   $( function() {
      var xColors =['red','green','yellow','blue'];
      $('.dot li').click( function() {
        $('.wrapper').css('background', xColors[$(this).index()] );    
      });
   });
   ```

### [LIve - DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R9uf9/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Dont really understand your question still hope this shed some light :

You  can save the color in li something like:

```
    <div class="slider-nav">
    <ul class="dot">
        <li  class='red'><a href="#">iphone 5<span class="bullet">1</span></a></li>
        <li  class='yellow'><a href="#">htc one <span class="bullet">2</span></a></li>
        <li  class='blue'><a href="#">ipad mini<span class="bullet">3</span></a> </li>
        <li  class='green'><a href="#">droid z<span class="bullet">4</span></a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>

$( function() {
  $('.dot li').click( function() {
    $('.wrapper').css('background',$(this).attr('class'));  
});
```